# How can I copy my git revision history into svn?

Tags: git-svn

I use Git, but some of my colleagues are unable to move away from SVN right now. We want the integration between the two systems to be seamless -- all of our development has been in git so far, so we need to copy that over into svn with complete revision history.

I've been able to jigger this such that it copies the repository in a single commit, but I would like it to copy *all* of the history. I would imagine that this should be pretty easy with git svn dcommit, etc., but it hasn't worked out that way -- merges seem to only go in as a single commit, rebasing kills git-svn, and pull just merges.

So, I've been trying things for the last couple of hours, but can't seem to get it. Tailor almost works, but dies amidst import with what appears to be a bug.

All help is appreciated, and thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating the svn repository, git-svn clonning it, git-pull'ing from the old git repo (the one with all the history), git-rebase those changes into the master branch, then git-svn dcommitting the changes up to svn? That's just off the top of my head, but might work.

Googling for "git svn export" also showed up this : http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/10/29/3848124 which seems similar to what I've just described, but with more detail and accuracy, which should get you there.

But knowing Git - i'm sure this will be possible for you :)

Let me know how you get on! I'm also interested in this problem...